# How would I split box plots made using geom_boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using r studio to try to create a plot for RTs across conditions, with separate data for each of three speeds and four conditions, currently if I create a box plot it makes one for the entire condition (whole, front, back, deleted) rather than whole 33, whole 50, whole 100, front 33, etc.. I am unsure how to deal with this.

```
newData3$TaskName <- factor(newData3$TaskName, levels = c('Whole', 'Front', 'Back', 'Deleted'))
newData3$display <- factor(newData3$display, levels = c('33ms', '50ms', '100ms'))

ggplot(newData3, aes(x = display, y = RT, group = TaskName, fill = TaskName)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(), alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('darkorange3', 'royalblue1', 'seagreen4', 'goldenrod2')) +
  geom_point(data = newData3, mapping = aes(x = display, y = RT, colour = TaskName, alpha = .6, size = 1)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('darkorange3', 'royalblue1', 'seagreen4', 'goldenrod2')) +
  labs(title = 'RTs', x = 'Condition', y = 'RT (ms)') +
  facet_wrap(~ TaskName) + theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        title = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16),
        strip.text = element_text(colour = 'black', size = 14))
```

I am trying to make something like this but with box plots:
[image]

But this is as far as I have got:
[image]

This is what my data looks like:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: maybe `facet_grid( Condition ~ TaskName)`?

Comment: To get a boxplot to match the bars, you will need to set your `group` aesthetic to match `display`, not `TaskName`.   You should still be able to fix the x axis via using facets like you're doing here - I personally think it's the most straightforward way.  If you can share a reprex, we can help more specifically here... although it may be difficult if your dataset is not small, as it seems to be.